# Regex that does not match any string with any instance of forward or backslash

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, string

I want a regex that will fail to match any string which contains either a forward slash or backslash

I have this regex now

```
/[^\\|/]/i
```

in theory, this would not match

```
aaaa/ooa

age\nange\
```

but for some reason, this regex seems to match the first character in the string, if the character is a letter, and with the global flag

```
 /[^\\|/]/ig
```

it will match any non-forward-slash or non-back-slash

how can I get a regex that will not match any string that contains a forward slash or backslash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to anchor your regex and use quantifier:

```
^[^\/\\]+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gV7gI6/1)

Use `*` instead of `+` if you want to match empty strings also.